# Angularjs ng-disabled button for several checkbox input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following plunler :

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJq0Qy3j5nGr1eJ9f9QA?p=preview

What I'd like to do is to enable the button if at least one checkbox is checked.

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeSelectedRows()">Remove Selected Rows</button>
```

This works great :

```
<button ng-disabled="mySwitch">Click</button>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitch">
```

but when I apply it to my example, it does nothing.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/WpK2KXtAJC3gfl8MoMlZ?p=preview

You can run checks if any of the items in the model is `true` using `$scope.$watch` function:

```
 $scope.$watch('tableSelection', function(val){
    if(val){ //if value is not empty
      $scope.disableRemoveButton = true;
      for (var i in val){ //iterate props of the Object
        if(val.hasOwnProperty(i)){ //only needed props
          if(val[i] == true) { 
          $scope.disableRemoveButton = false;
          }
        }
        }
      }
  }, true)
```

We also introduce additional flag `$scope.disableRemoveButton` that is being changed in case if there's true value in model. That corresponds to `<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="disableRemoveButton"` in the template.